# How to search address book with a phone number?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just want to search my IPhone's address book by a received call's phone number. How can I proceed further in this case? Suppose my received call is in the format of (ISD code) xxxxxxxxxx, like (+1 1234567890) or (001 1234567890) or (+11234567890) or (+1 (123) 456-7890) or (1234567890 without ISD code) or something else. So how can I search the entire address book data base to get the contacts info by using only (ISD CODE)1234567890? Can somebody help me please?

Regards,
Prathap.

Comment: By searching over internet and looking into IPhone SDK API, I came across to these, "TILL NOW THERE IS NO WAY TO DO THIS".

 The address book stores the phone numbers (if you're adding a phone number through "contacts" the ph num stored in different format else if the phone number is copied from SIM then it saved in a different format) in a formatted way based upon the localization settings. So the phone number should be formatted based upon localization settings and searched entire addres sbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By searching over internet and looking into API, I came across to these, "TILL NOW THERE IS NO WAY TO DO THIS". 
The address book stores the phone numbers (if you're adding a phone number through "contacts" the ph num will be stored in a different format else if the phone number is copied from SIM then it saved in a different format) in a formatted way based upon the localization settings. So to get the contact with the phone number, the phone number should be formatted based upon localization settings and searched entire address book.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an interesting thing i learned about how Android handles caller id (how they quickly and easily get the name for an incoming call)

Instead of storing the phone numbers internally in an address book database as +1 (555) 666-1234, store them in reverse order such as 43216665551. That way when a call comes, in reverse the incoming phone number (43216665551), take just the first 10 digits (4321666555), and have your SQL look something like "WHERE phone_number LIKE "4321666555%"

This doesn't really answer your question, but someone may find this useful

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the spaces and brackets and compare only the digits, with a longest suffix matching.

And searching through the ENTIRE address book is the only way, as the SDK did not provide a ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithNumber. I wished they would provide one.

Answer (score 0):

The following method will return an array that contains all of the contacts that have the given phone number.  It doesn't matter if the phoneNumber is just numbers or if its formatted and contains dashes etc.

This method took 0.02 seconds to search 250 contacts on my iPhone 5 running iOS7.

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>


-(NSArray *)contactsContainingPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber {
    /*

     Returns an array of contacts that contain the phone number

     */

    // Remove non numeric characters from the phone number
    phoneNumber = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    // Create a new address book object with data from the Address Book database
    CFErrorRef error = nil;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);
    if (!addressBook) {
        return [NSArray array];
    } else if (error) {
        CFRelease(addressBook);
        return [NSArray array];
    }

    // Requests access to address book data from the user
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {});

    // Build a predicate that searches for contacts that contain the phone number
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^(id record, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue( (__bridge ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        BOOL result = NO;
        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++) {
            NSString *contactPhoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
            contactPhoneNumber = [[contactPhoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
            if ([contactPhoneNumber rangeOfString:phoneNumber].location != NSNotFound) {
                result = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
        return result;
    }];

    // Search the users contacts for contacts that contain the phone number
    NSArray *allPeople = (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook));
    NSArray *filteredContacts = [allPeople filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    CFRelease(addressBook);

    return filteredContacts;
}
```